# How to summarize text with ChatGPT in batches?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I need to summarize a large collection of texts (each text by itself) and currently doing this:

```
for text_to_summarize in all_text:
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[ 
            {"role": "user", "content": f"Summarize into one sentence: {text_to_summarize}"},
        ],
    )
    summary = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
```

But this is very slow (I have 300k+ texts).

I found on the OpenAI website that you can do batches with [some models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/error-mitigation), by doing `openai.Completion.create`, but I can't figure out how to do this with ChatGPT.

Answer (score -1):

check this: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/summarization

A frequent scenario is the need to condense lengthy documents, which often poses a challenge due to context window limitations. Unlike in question-answering, where one can employ semantic search techniques to isolate only the most pertinent text chunks, this is not feasible as there is no specific question to address when summarizing the entire text. In this case, the most common approach is to divide the document into segments and recursively summarize each segment individually, then group the summaries and repeat the process until only one summary remains.